# Refreshing page without losing checkboxes information in cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, checkbox

I'm developing a website with CakePhp.
I have a view to select some items on a list, via checkboxes in a form, and each item has a "more info" link which refreshes the page with additional information of this item.

The problem is that if I click any "more info" link, I obviously lose the data about what checkboxes were selected before. The only thing I come up with is updating $this->Session each time a checkbox is changed, but I need to trigger a function in a controller when this happens.

Is there any other solution?

I've been searching everywhere and I've found some things about Javascript and JQuery, but I have no idea of how to do it this way neither.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at making an Ajax call to get the specific information?

Comment: Depending on the amount of data, could you not include the 'more info' as part of the initial page response but hidden eg set div's style to `display:none` then show them once the more info link is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind sending all the text it's quite easy:

```
<div class='article'>
    <div>short text<a href="#" class="morebtn">more info</a></div>
    <div class="more hidden">long text</div>
</div>
```

jquery part

```
$(".article").on('click', '.morebtn', function(){
  $(this).parents('.article').find('.more').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

css

```
.hidden { display: none }
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Ggw/)

The better solution is to use ajax request. Also not that hard to implement.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Ggw/1/) showing the very basic request. You could use the full [$ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) request too if you want need to do more advanced requests.

*note that the example of the ajax request does not work due to invalid url. The url need to be from the same origin as the current page (same protocol, domain and port) to make it work. There are work arounds but that's a different issue*

Comment: Alternatively, he could set the content of the div using an AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on AJAX, it's a really cool technology which will make it very simple to do what you need. Outline:

- When the button is clicked, the browser sends an AJAX request to the server for the text to display somewhere on the page.
- When the response (some HTML fragment from the server) is received by the browser, a function is called which looks like so:

  function(data) {
       $('#description').html(data);
   }

Doing AJAX requests is 5-10 lines of code (mostly configuration + building the URL).

The main work is on server side where you need to write a controller which provides the texts.

Since the page is never reloaded, there is no need to preserve the form values.

To learn AJAX, [start with this tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery).